# How to reset numbered sections in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, sections, toctree

I have several documents that are independant from each others:

```
index.rst
foo.rst
bar.rst
conf.py
Makefile
```

I would like to access `foo.rst` from `index.rst`, but I would like the two subdocuments to start their numbering at 1.

In `index.rst` I have:

```
.. toctree::
   :maxdepth: 2
   :numbered:

   foo
   bar
```

But, bar will take the number `2.` and with this `bar.rst` I will get `2.1 Tomatoes`.

```
=====
Title
=====

Tomatoes
========

Cucumbers
=========
```

and I would like this rendering:

```
1. Tomatoes
2. Cucumbers
```

How is that possible?

Comment: But what about the "Title" section? It looks like you want to ignore it.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. When you start an article, the title of this article isn't named `1.`. Only the first section of this document is named. Here, the first section is `Tomatoes`.

Comment: I don't understand. The first section in bar.rst is `Title`.

Comment: In my case `Title` is the title of the document. If I remove it, the document will be named `Tomatoes`.

Comment: The only way to reset section numbering (that I can think of) is to use a second `toctree`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have it both ways. See Sphinx documentation for [Section numbering under the `toctree` directive](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/markup/toctree.html) for the explanation:

> **Section numbering**
>
> If you want to have section numbers even in HTML output, give the **toplevel** `toctree` a numbered option. For example:
>
> ```
> .. toctree::
>   :numbered:
>
>   foo
>   bar
> ```
>
> Numbering then starts at the heading of `foo`. Sub-toctrees are automatically numbered (don’t give the numbered flag to those).